# Jenkins: белый экран после входа

Tags: debian, jenkins

Установил на сервер Jenkins. После первой настройки вошел и вижу просто белый экран. С чем это может быть связано?

Система - Debian 9

Comment: с тем, что вы не посмотрели логи.

Comment: посмотрел тут - /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log - ничего нету

Comment: перегрузил командой service jenkins restart - заработало